# How can I add an outlet off of a conduit body?

Tags: electrical, wiring, conduit

I want to add an electrical outlet near this point.  On the other side of the wall from this junction is my main breaker panel so I intend to run the wires from the panel through this junction. The problem is that there is no other opening in the junction.

Ideally I would have an opening on the right side of this junction and run conduit outside the wall about one foot to the new outlet.  What type of junction box should I buy?  It needs to go through the wall into the back of the breaker panel.  I’m not sure I’m searching for the right terms and can’t find a box that has all the openings I want.

What’s the easiest way to do this and still have it look tidy?  Not sure it matters for my question but this will be a 240 volt, 30 amp outlet for a car charger.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What diameter is the conduit shown?

Comment: The conduit is 7/8" outer diameter.

Comment: Can you provide a picture of the back of the panel (with the panel cover removed) showing where that cable enters?

Comment: It says 3/4 on the LB cover

Comment: What size wire and how many are already in that conduit? It might not be as easy as pulling extra wires through it - it may already be at fill capacity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to pull the wires back through the LB to install a new conduit body. There's a product by Arlington Industries called [ANYBody](https://www.elliottelectric.com/P/Item/ARL/931/). It's a conduit body with removable hubs that allows you to create any configuration required.

Also, [here's a link](http://www.aifittings.com/landing/anybody/) to Arlington's website for that product. You can enter your zip code and find a local supplier. Most electrical supply houses carry this product and have counter sales.

Comment: There's a bit more to it than that, as extra wire is needed. Some slack will need to be found, or a new length of cable will need to be pulled.

Comment: What do you mean? Just need to pull 2 #10 THHN wires to the EV charger. Easy.

Comment: I guess I interpreted the request as a split in the circuit at the LB. Maybe that's not what was meant.